# Appending conditions in a numerical loop (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, loops, conditional-statements

I have four IF statements, is it possible to rewrite this into a neater loop, where the [i] may be '4' or higher.

```
if (typed.length == 1 && c.charAt(0) == typed[0]) { 
    //something ; 
    return false;
}

if (typed.length == 2 && c.charAt(0) == typed[0] 
    && c.charAt(1) == typed[1]) {  
    //something ; 
    return false;
}

if (typed.length == 3 && c.charAt(0) == typed[0] 
    && c.charAt(1) == typed[1] && c.charAt(2) == typed[2]) {  
    //something ; 
    return false;
}

if (typed.length == 4 && c.charAt(0) == typed[0] 
    && c.charAt(1) == typed[1] && c.charAt(2) == typed[2] 
    && c.charAt(3) == typed[3]) {  
    //something ; 
    return false;
}
```

Comment: is the order of `c` and `typed` always the same, or can `c` contain a randomly set characters that may be contained in `typed`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks to me like something like this should to it:

```
if (c.substr(0, typed.length) == typed)
```

Possibly `typed.join()` if `typed` is an array.

Comment: I agree with this method, but Brandon was asking specifically for a loop.

Comment: @Yanick I have to assume a lot about this question, since there's little info... :)

Comment: @Jason The OP doesn't necessarily always know what he wants... ;)

Comment: @+1: beat me to it! because the question can be simplified as checked whether "typed" is same as a predefined "c"

Comment: brilliant! thanks, I don't need the loop anymore with your solution.

Comment: right now, it is prioritised to do search at zero of c - substr(0,..), but if zero anchor of c list is all invalid, is it possible to search otherwise.

Comment: right now I'm checking point zero of c (list) to typed (search term), if all the c items of the list does not match the typed with (0 - type.length), I'm considering if I can have a more robust intelli-search, which prioritises at point 0, but can move on to search other positions of c items.

Comment: @Brandon I think you will have to show more details about what kind of data you're actually working with and what the goal is. Right now all I can do is guess. Maybe open a new question about intelligent search algorithms?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
for(var x=0; x<typed.length; x++)
{
   if(c.chatAt(x)!=typed[x]) { return false; }
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i=1; i<=4; ++i){
  if (typed.length!=i) continue;
  var OK = true;
  for (var j=0;j<i;++j){
    OK = OK && (c.charAt(0)==typed[j]);
  }
  if (OK){
    // something
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget about two nested loops, or assuming `c` and `typed` are "ordered", just look for the char in `c`

```
for (var i=0; i<typed.length; i++) {
   if (c.indexOf(typed.charAt(i)) >= 0) {  // or c.indexOf(typed.charAt(i)) == i
      return false;
   }
}
return true;
```